# Member "team1Score" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type (contract Game) - Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm on a course and have run into a problem.

I am trying to make a function that shows the difference in team score from the perspective of the team in the variable teamNumber.

My issue is that when trying to import the variable "team1Score" or "team2Score" from the other contract Game.sol I get the error - **Member "team1Score" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type (contract Game)**

Here is the Game.sol contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Game {
    int public team1Score;
    int public team2Score;

    enum Teams { Team1, Team2 }

    function addScore(Teams teamNumber) external {
        if (teamNumber == Teams.Team1) {
            team1Score +=1;
        } else if (teamNumber == Teams.Team2) {
            team2Score +=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Bet.sol which references Game.sol. The problem lies within the function "getScoreDifference"

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "./Game.sol";

contract Bet {
    address public game;



    constructor (address gameContract) {
        game = gameContract;
    }
     
    // calculates the payout of a bet based on the score difference between the two teams
    function calculatePayout(uint amount, int scoreDifference) private pure returns(uint) {
        uint abs = uint(scoreDifference > 0 ? scoreDifference : scoreDifference * -1);  
        uint odds = 2 ** abs;
        if(scoreDifference < 0) {
            return amount + amount / odds;
        }
        return amount + amount * odds;
    }

    function getScoreDifference (Game.Teams x) public view returns (int256){
        if (x == Game.Teams.Team1) {
            return Game.team1Score - Game.team2Score;
        } else if (x == Game.Teams.Team2) {
            return Game.team2Score - Game.team1Score;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
constructor (address gameContract) {
    game = gameContract;
}
```

should be

```
constructor (address gameContract) {
    game = Game(gameContract);
}
```

and

```
function getScoreDifference (Game.Teams x) public view returns (int256){
    if (x == Game.Teams.Team1) {
        return Game.team1Score - Game.team2Score;
    } else if (x == Game.Teams.Team2) {
        return Game.team2Score - Game.team1Score;
    }
}
```

should be

```
function getScoreDifference (Game.Teams x) public view returns (int256){
        if (x == Game.Teams.Team1) {
            return game.team1Score - game.team2Score;
        } else if (x == Game.Teams.Team2) {
            return game.team2Score - game.team1Score;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getScoreDifference (Game.Teams x) public view returns (int256) {
  if (x == Game.Teams.Team1) {
    return game.team1Score - game.team2Score;
  } else if (x == Game.Teams.Team2) {
    return game.team2Score - game.team1Score;
  }
}
```

^this will still fail because the methods of an imported contract are available only as functions, i.e; `contract.variableName()`

Instead, it should be this to pass all tests:

```
function getScoreDifference (Game.Teams x) public view returns (int256 score) {
  if (x == Game.Teams.Team1) {
    return score = game.team1Score() - game.team2Score();
  } else if (x == Game.Teams.Team2) {
    return score = game.team2Score() - game.team1Score();
  }
}
```